# Windows IoT - Raspberry pi

Tags: face-recognition, windowsiot

I got a question on does anyone have any idea how would you connect a python code in linux(raspberry pi) and transfer the data collected to update the database in visual studio?

In my case would be facial recognition and I would want to send the recognized face to visual studio in windows so that it is able to update the database but I have no idea how to start.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect a python code in linux with raspberry pi, you'll need to use the [PyWinDevices](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/master/PyWinDevices). Download it from [here](https://github.com/ms-iot/python/releases/download/v1.0Alpha/pywindevices.zip) and import to your python project.

Normally, the way we transfer the data is through [Azure IoT Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/). For your linux python client, you can use azure-iot-sdk for python. One way to do that is to pull the source code from [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks.git), and have it [compiled](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/python/device/readme.md). You can find some code sample in [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks/blob/master/doc/get_started/python-run-sample.md).

In your case, first send your recognized face to the hub, then receive it in windows client. Depending on the coding language you're using in your Visual Studio project, if it's C#, follow this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted/) to create your windows C# project.